# Armature - tentacle or cable with extendable and retractable joints?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

[image: This is the machine in question whose movements I'd like to]

This is the machine in question whose movements (1.35 -1.38, source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WfpfpzknBo8&t=266s) I'd like to replicate via applying armature. My mesh: [image]

How do I apply a tentacle armature after the limb fully extends its joints, to make the tentacle retract into the body? Also, how do I make the body rotate at 1.26? Again, I'd like to replicate all this machine's movements, as per this video.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this tutorial? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKfdy050JMQ

Comment: @moonboots thanks for this recommendation